# SQL: How do I save a query result as a new temp table?

Tags: sql, variables, subquery, common-table-expression, temp-tables

I am beginner of SQL. How do I save the query result of Part A (already have multiple subqueries using WITH clause) as a new temp table, so that I can use it for the query in Part B (because the aggregation in Part B is based on Part A)? In the end, I would like to have results of Part A and Part B separately. I've tried to solution from other posts, but it doesn't seem to work for my problem as I have multiple subqueries using the WITH clause). Thank you in advance for your help!

```
/****** Part A ******/
WITH DL_source AS
    (SELECT
        LogID
        ,HashID
        ,DeviceDateTime
        ,LAG(DeviceDateTime, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY HashID ORDER BY HashID, DeviceDateTime, LogID) AS Last_DeviceDateTime
        ,TotalSecondsSpent
        ,PageViews
        ,Pages
        ,PrevPage
        ,IEM
        ,CommCode
        ,ContentTag
        ,SearchKeyword
        ,TaggedMember
        ,TargetMember
    FROM (SELECT
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY HashID, DeviceDate, HourOfDay, MinOfHour, SecOfMin) AS LogID
       ,HashID
       ,CAST(DeviceDate AS DATETIME)                                                                
       + CAST(TIMEFROMPARTS(HourOfDay, MinOfHour, SecOfMin,0 ,0) AS DATETIME) AS DeviceDateTime
       ,TotalSecondsSpent
       ,PageViews
       ,Pages
       ,PrevPage
       ,IEM
       ,CommCode
       ,ContentTag
       ,SearchKeyword
       ,TaggedMember
       ,TargetMember
    FROM [DM_RAW].[dbo].[WebAnalyticsVisit]                                 
    WHERE DeviceDate IS NOT NULL
    AND DeviceDate <> '1900-01-01'
    AND HashID IS NOT NULL
    AND HashID <> '') AS DL_DateTime),
DL_Session_Source AS (
    SELECT
        LogID
        ,HashID
        ,DeviceDateTime
        ,Last_DeviceDateTime
        ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DeviceDateTime, LEAD(DeviceDateTime, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY HashID ORDER BY DeviceDateTime ASC)) AS Min_btw_Page
        ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(minute, Last_DeviceDateTime, DeviceDateTime) <30 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS New_Session_flag
        ,TotalSecondsSpent
        ,PageViews
        ,Pages
        ,PrevPage
        ,IEM
        ,CommCode
        ,ContentTag
        ,SearchKeyword
        ,TaggedMember
        ,TargetMember
    FROM DL_source)
SELECT
        LogID
        ,HashID
        ,DeviceDateTime
        ,Last_DeviceDateTime
        ,Min_btw_Page
        ,New_Session_flag
        ,SUM(New_Session_flag) OVER (ORDER BY HashID, DeviceDateTime, LogID) AS Session_Num
        ,TotalSecondsSpent
        ,PageViews
        ,Pages
        ,PrevPage
        ,IEM
        ,CommCode
        ,ContentTag
        ,SearchKeyword
        ,TaggedMember
        ,TargetMember
FROM DL_Session_Source

/****** Part B ******/
SELECT *,
    Session_Num
    ,HashID
    ,COUNT(*) AS Num_Page
    ,MIN(DeviceDateTime) AS First_Page
    ,MAX(DeviceDateTime) AS Last_Page
FROM #cte_Visit_Record_cheunghm4532
GROUP BY Session_Num, HashID
```

Comment: What do you mean, "separately"? Your queries in your Part A seem completely unrelated to your Part B.. Always tag the database you're actually using, sql is just the name of a standard and often questions on here that mention it need also to mention the db name to be answerable. Point to the tag and read the tooltip

Comment: Hi @Caius Jard, my apology for not posting the table I am using. I will keep that in mind the next time when I post a question. Thanks and have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick'n'easy option: When you get to the SELECT part at the bottom of Part A, put an [INTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) expression in.

Note for these statements, I have reduced the number of fields etc and replaced with `...` for brevity/clarity.

```
WITH DL_source AS
    (SELECT
    ... ),
DL_Session_Source AS (
    SELECT ...
    FROM DL_source)
SELECT
        LogID
        ,HashID
        ...
        ,TargetMember
INTO #cte_Visit_Record_cheunghm4532        -- Added this row
FROM DL_Session_Source;
```

Note that the above creates a new table - it will not insert into an existing table.

A more thorough/flexible version is to first create the temporary table, then instead of the SELECT above, make it an INSERT e.g.,

```
CREATE TABLE #cte_Visit_Record_cheunghm4532 (LogID int, HashID varchar(32), ...);

WITH DL_source AS
    (SELECT
    ... ),
DL_Session_Source AS (
    SELECT ...
    FROM DL_source)
INSERT INTO #cte_Visit_Record_cheunghm4532 (LogID, HashID, ...)
   SELECT LogID
         ,HashID
         ...
   FROM DL_Session_Source;
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, it's you again @seanb!! I create a separate post here as I am worried that I bothered you too much, and you showed up and answer my question again! You are my hero, saving me twice within 24 hours lol

Comment: But why not just make it another with?

Comment: The main advantage of a temp table is that you can do multiple analyses on it. Crunch the data into a temp table then do one command (like his Part B), then another different one, etc.  Sometimes it also helps with cardinality estimates and bad plans - breaking the query up into two parts allows the query optimiser to start again on the second half with better estimates (and therefore better performance). However, as @Caius says, if you're only doing one command on the final output, then yes - you could just make it into another 'with'.